# How to filter object array and return only 2 of 4 properties and formated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, filter, vuejs3

I receive from API the following object array:

```
{id: 0, color: 'Red', code:'AAA'}
{id: 1, color: 'Blue', code:'BBB'}
{id: 2, color: 'Orange', code:'CCC'}
{id: 3, color: 'Black', code:'DDD'}
```

how can I return it for another array but only if id is > 1 and like this:

```
const arrayFiltered = { 'Orange#CCC', 'Black#DDD' }
```

I need convert it in a string array and concatenate 2 atributes...

Comment: I think you may have put the example in the question incorrectly? Since the "array" is missing and the list of objects would throw an error. The output is also invalid.

Comment: Oh, yes... I forget to put the [ ];

Comment: (and the commas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming given array is `givenArr`

```
const givenArr = [
  {id: 0, color: 'Red', code:'AAA'},
  {id: 1, color: 'Blue', code:'BBB'},
  {id: 2, color: 'Orange', code:'CCC'},
  {id: 3, color: 'Black', code:'DDD'}
]

result = givenArr.filter((val) => val.id > 1).map((item) => `${item.color}#${item.code}`)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is invalid.  arrayFiltered will be an array not an object, its output would be like
`['Orange#CCC', 'Black#DDD']`

`const arrayFiltered = arrayInput.filter(c => c.id > 1).map(c => c.color + c.code);`

Comment: Nice!! and If I don´t need any condition just use a function map, correct?

Comment: If you don't need the list filtered you can remove the `.filter(...)` part.